# Pushing a string to an array in AJAX success function in jquery not working

Tags: jquery, arrays, push

I am trying to customise the jquery chat bot using the sample plugin present in  https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/engage-audience-conversational-chatty.html.

I am using the following code:

```
var tags=[];
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    /*method type*/
    url: "sample.jsp",
    dataType: "text",
    data: "usrname=" + $('#uname').val(),
    async: false // To push values to an array 
}) //ajax
.done(function(data) {
    alert(data); // it displayed all the content which is needed for the array correctly
    tags.push(data);
})
.fail(function(f) {
    alert("Chatbot Module fetch failed!!");
});
```

I am retrieving 'data' as a String from java method:

if I use following line directly into javascript function it is working fine:

```
function addArr() {
  tags.push({type: 'input', tag: 'text', name: 'converse', 'chat-msg': 'Hi Welcome!!'},);
}
```

but if I try to push the string  in to array it is not working. I am framing the string content as given below:

```
// java code:
result = "{type: 'input', tag: 'text', name: 'converse', 'chat-msg': 'Hi Welcome!!'},"
return result;
```

Comment: Is `tags.push(JSON.parse(data))` working ?

Comment: I am seeing this error in browser console SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 11 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: try this `tags.append('custom_name', JSON.stringify(data));`

Comment: @AjantaR can you add returned data to your question?

Comment: @Rezash Why `JSON.stringify` ? And why `tags.append` ?

Comment: Don't use `async: false` (your browser should already complain about that setting)

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick response for all of you . DATA RETURNED AS  {type: 'input', tag: 'text', name: 'converse', 'chat-msg': 'Hi Welcome!!'},

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323)

Comment: @Andreas if I dont use async:false then I am not getting alert/any other process in sucess .

Answer (score 0):

So what you're trying to do is push a js object to an array, but you're getting a JSON string as a response? If that's the case you could change dataType to "json".

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    /*method type*/
    url: "sample.jsp",
    dataType: "json", // dataType -> json
    data: "usrname=" + $('#uname').val(),
    async: false // To push values to an array 
})
```

The other way is parsing the string on success but it's cleaner to change the dataType.

```
var tags=[];
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    /*method type*/
    url: "sample.jsp",
    dataType: "text",
    data: "usrname=" + $('#uname').val(),
    async: false // To push values to an array 
}) //ajax
.done(function(data) {
    tags.push(JSON.parse(data)); // Parse string  JSON.parse(data)
})
.fail(function(f) {
    alert("Chatbot Module fetch failed!!");
});
```

Comment: I have tried 2 nd method but it is showing error in browser console as given in earlier post

Comment: I tried to use 1 st method ie:  dataType: "JSON" and it worked!!!!.. Thanks a lot

Comment: { type: "input",
    tag: "radio",
    name: "module",
    "chat-msg": "Hi  Welcome " + $('#uname').val() + "!!" + " Choose any of the colour given below!!",
    children: [{
        value: "red",
        text: "red",
      },
      {
        value: "blue",
        text: "blue",
      },
      {
        value: "green",
        text: "green",
      }
    ]
  },
); //push ends. How to send array {'red','blue','green'} in the json object. I could view the question but to choose the colour, it shows undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I have used  dataType: "json", // dataType -> json

and then I have used JSONObject and JSONArray to create the array.

```
enter code here

      JSONObject dao = new JSONObject();
      JSONObject dao1 = new JSONObject();
      ResultSet rs = null;
      JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();

        String modules="";
        String result ="";
        String modl="";
        String qry = "";
        qry = "SELECT color FROM allmodules";
         rs = db1.execSQL(qry);

        while( rs.next() )
        {
            modules = rs.getString("color") ;
            dao1.put("value", modules);
            dao1.put("text", modules);
            ja.add(new JSONObject(dao1));
        }

        dao.put("type","input");
        dao.put("tag", "radio");
        dao.put("name","module");
        dao.put("chat-msg", "Hi Welcome" + user + "!!" + " Choose any of the color given below!!");
        dao.put("children",ja);


    return dao.toString();
```